# Python variable stuck inside of my function

Tags: python

The variable is stuck inside of the function because the code outside the function can't recongnize the variable(Number).

I make the random integer("Number") in the function("Roll_Dice") so when I call it with a button("b") it gets created and recreated.

I've tried to find the solution for this but all I could find was to use return function which makes sense but that doesn't work either, I prob used it wrong but tell me if I did please

And yes I am very aware that this is a very noob question but that's okay I hope right? :)

Here is the code, again I am a beginner at programming

```
import random
from tkinter import *

# here we assign the Tkinter window to a variable and give it a messure
window = Tk()
window.geometry("200x100")

#defining the function Roll_Dice generating the number from 1 to 6 at random
def Roll_Dice():
    Number = random.randint(1, 6)
    print(Number)
    return Number()

# now we make a button with a name
b = Button(window,text = "roll dice", activebackground = "pink",relief= GROOVE,command = Roll_Dice, pady = 15)
b.pack(side = RIGHT)

# here we make a label to show the result of the dice (for now in symbol, later in image)
l =Label(window, text = Number, pady = 5)
l.pack(side = LEFT)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: `Number` is a `int`, not a function. You can't `call()` it.

Comment: So it's `return Number`.

Comment: As a side note, have a look at the official PEP 8 style guide. It describes the very well respected conventions of Python that you really, really should follow. For example, only class names are capitalized, so your variable should be `number`, not `Number`.

Comment: And finally, if you're a beginner, you should follow some good tutorial. SO is not a good place to replace that.

Comment: oh and btw I changed it to return number instead of return Number() (I changed the variable to number aswell) but the int still hasn't been defined outside the function Roll_Dice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Number` variable is essentially lost after being "computed", because the code does nothing with it:

- if `Number` isn't returned, it's cleaned up when function exits (read up on *scopes*, *namespaces*, local / global variables)
- when `Number` is returned, there's nothing happening with it, because Tk ignores button callback return values

What you want to do is to write a function that "calculates" the random number and sets text label.  That function (accepting no arguments and returning nothing) should be your callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can create other function `rand_num()` to generate random number and return its value then call it in label text.

Also, modify `Roll_Dice()` function for updating label text when button pressed/clicked with `rand_num()` return value.

```
import random
from tkinter import *

# here we assign the Tkinter window to a variable and give it a messure
window = Tk()
window.geometry("200x100")

#defining the function Roll_Dice generating the number from 1 to 6 at random
def rand_num():
    number = random.randint(1, 6)
    return number

def Roll_Dice():
    l['text'] = rand_num()

# now we make a button with a name
b = Button(window,text = "roll dice", activebackground = "pink",relief= GROOVE,command = Roll_Dice, pady = 15)
b.pack(side = RIGHT)

# here we make a label to show the result of the dice (for now in symbol, later in image)
l =Label(window, text = rand_num(), pady = 5)
l.pack(side = LEFT)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Damn I don't know yet what that is you wrote the line under def Roll_Dice(): but I think I understand a little bit, but how do you call that?

Comment: l is label function, you can get the value of the parameter just like dict. l['text'] in Roll_Dice is basically value of 'text' which is rand_num() function, and b command will call Roll_Dice() which is trigger rand_num() and display it in label text (l['text])